# Live/Reactive Aggregation in FeathersJS

Tags: feathersjs

I am trying to implement a real-time app with FeathersJS and Feathers-Vuex.

A simple example - A todo app where users can add goals, add tasks to goals, and an effort (1-5) to each task. I want to find out the total effort needed for the goal. Anytime the effort of a task changes (CRUD), the effort of the goal gets updated.

So something like -

```
Goal: G1 (11/15)
Tasks: T1 (4/5), T2 (2/3), T3 (5/5)
```

How do I calculate this and keep it in sync in FeathersJS + FeathersVuex?

What I've tried so far -

1. FastJoin to populate this data to each goal record but it wasn't reactive - Not sure how to "listen" to changes to "Tasks"
2. Hooks and storing stats in the database - It worked for a while but started getting out of hands (when the more services were involved in calculations) and I ended up with too much coupling.
3. Loading everything in Vuex and calculating it on the front-end - Worked well for prototyping but doesn't work for actual cases where there would be too many records to be able to pre-load everything.
4. A custom Service - "GoalStats" which calculates the relevant stats by aggregating things from multiple services [Read that it is the recommended way for this]

What I can't seem to figure out is - how to keep things reactive when data is computed/aggregated across services. (Eg. Adding a new task in the above example changes the goal priority)

Still relatively new to FeathersJS and FeathersVuex - so not really sure what I am missing here.

---

**Update**
Here is what I have settled on for now - Use hooks from all the dependent services to trigger an empty PATCH request on the Custom Service (if needed). In FeathersVuex, I have added the service and it gets updated.

So, in context of the example above, I am using the before and after hooks of Tasks service to check if Effort value is being changed, or if the task is being added/removed. If so, I dispatch a PATCH request which calls the GET behind the scenes in my custom service, and recalculates the stats which then follows the existing events flow.

Not sure if there is a better way to go about this and/or if there are best practices around managing these cross-service "triggers"